# Микроразметка Organization и LocalBusiness

Tags: микроразметка

подскажите конкретно пожалуйста. Вопрос в следующем, мне нужно добавить микроразметки: Organization и LocalBusiness, но на каких страницах их добавлять? На всех сразу, то есть добавить в футер и не парится или же на странице контактов?